# How can I add new items to my session array if value is not already in it? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to add new items to my array if they don't already exist but below code shows me an error:

```
// Check if session exists
if(!isset($_SESSION['coupon'])){
  // Create array from session
  $_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'] = array();
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'][$coupon])){
  // Add couponcode to session if it does not already exist
  $_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'][] = $coupon;
}
```

`$_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'][] = $coupon;`

Gives: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings`

But I thought this was the way to add to the array, if I remove the brackets it just replaces the value everytime.

I have `session_start();` everywhere at the top of my pages.

Comment: That code works fine. Somewhere else in your code you must be setting `$_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode']` to a string, or perhaps the error is occuring on a different line?

Comment: @Nick This is all code I have for the coupon session, the only part I didn't include is the part where I get the $_POST value which contains the actual coupon code but that shouldn't effect the session code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_push():

```
if(empty($_SESSION['coupon'])){
   // Create array from session
   $_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'] = array();
}
else
{
  if(!in_array( $coupon,$_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'])) //check in array available
  {
    array_push($_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'], $coupon); //push to array
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not add new values with above code, the first time the code is added then all attempts after nothing new is added.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,do not put blindly session_start() on top of every page. It will start session again even if a previous session was running and will refresh your all values, so first thing, change that to:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
   session_start();
}
```

this way it starts the session only if it doesn't exist.

Now, you are getting error because somehow your `$_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode']` is a string so add an additional check:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'][$coupon])){
  // Add couponcode to session if it does not already exist
  if (empty($_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode']) || !is_array($_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode']))) {
      $_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'] = [];
  }
  $_SESSION['coupon']['couponcode'][] = $coupon;
}
```